# JavaScript manipulating DOM (onclick event)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have this code that is supposed to add a div that is a red square every time I click the button. It happens that it adds the div I want 1 click yes and 1 click no. here's the code:

```js
var btnElement = document.querySelector('button');
console.log(btnElement);
btnElement.onclick = function() {
  var index = 0;
  var squareElementCreator = document.createElement('div');
  squareElementCreator.setAttribute('class', 'box');

  var containElement = document.querySelector('#app');
  containElement.appendChild(squareElementCreator);

  var squareElement = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
  console.log(squareElement[index]);
  squareElement[index].style.width = "100px";
  squareElement[index].style.height = "100px";
  squareElement[index].style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
  squareElement[index].style.margin = '10px';
  //console.log(squareElement);

  var container = document.querySelector('#app');
  container.appendChild(squareElement[index]);
  index++;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" />
  <button class="botao">Adicionar</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to create a for loop instead of your function? There is some logic issues as well.  Here are some pointers that might help you understand the code below:

1. Every variable declared within a function, will only be declared when that function is called.  After the function is called, the variables are destroyed and in most cases you cannot access them again.
2. You seem to be trying to select all your elements on the dom within the same function?  You wont need to do that if you just modify the style property before appending to the dom.
3. Take some time to do some research about the fundamentals, it will really help you put some quality code together.

```js
     var btnElement = document.querySelector('button');
     var containElement = document.querySelector('#app');
     btnElement.addEventListener('click', function () {

     var squareElement = document.createElement('div')
         squareElement.className = 'box'
         squareElement.style.width = "100px";
         squareElement.style.height = "100px";
         squareElement.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
         squareElement.style.margin = '10px';
     containElement.appendChild(squareElement)

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could benefit from HTML Templates and Slots

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots

```js
var btnElement = document.querySelector('button');

btnElement.onclick = function() {
  const template = document.getElementById('my-red-square').content.cloneNode(true);
  document.querySelector('#app').appendChild(template);
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" />
  <button class="botao">Adicionar</button>
</div>

<template id='my-red-square'>
<style>
    .box {
      width: 100px;
      height:100px;
      background-color: #00f;
      margin:10px;
    }
  </style>
<div class="box">
</div>
</template>
```